# Is there any difference between these two version of MySQL - 5.1.73-community-log Vs 5.1.73-community

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.1, configuration

I have installed **MySQL 5.1.73** in **Oracle LINUX 5** server. Just after RPM installation, I checked system variables and found that version is 5.1.73-community.
When I copid  `/usr/share/doc/MySQL-server-community-5.1.73/my-medium.cnf to /etc/my.cnf`
I **got 5.1.73-community-log** as value of version variable.
I am curious to know about what is the difference between 
**5.1.73-community** and **5.1.73-community-log**

Comment: This isn't an answer to your real question, but you really should not be using 5.1 for a new install.  The current version 5.6 has been out and stable for quite a while.  Many bug fixes, features, performance and security updates have been introduced since the 5.1 years

Comment: @atxdba, true, I recommend using a newer version of MySQL too. But FWIW the package repo for conservative Linux distros (e.g. RHEL) haven't even updated to 5.5 yet.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They are the same software. The `-log` suffix is simply appended to the version string at runtime.

Here's an explanation ([nearly from the last century](http://lists.mysql.com/mysql/77115)), by long-time MySQL author Paul DuBois:

> > I want to know what the -log means and how it got in there.
>
> -log is added if you start the server with logging turned on.
>
> -debug is added if you're running a debugging version of the server with debugging on.
>
> -demo is added if the server is running in demo mode

I verified this in the source, in `sql/mysqld.cc`, function `set_server_version()`:

```
. . .
if (opt_log || opt_slow_log || opt_bin_log)
  strmov(end, "-log");                        // This may slow down system
. . .
```

I think the meaning of that comment is *not* that appending four extra characters to the version slows down the system, but that logging may slow down the system, so it's worth noting to the DBA that logging is enabled.

Comment: +1 for quoting from `nearly the last century` and the gentle reminder about slowdowns due to logs.

Comment: As @RolandoMySQLDBA told, a simple and clear answer with the reference of `lists.mysql.com`.